# Adobe xd do not loading the files

Tags: adobe, adobe-xd

When i open a file in adobe xd , it will not complete the loading and just stop there!

[image]

No errors , its just stop there.

the files are not the problem , they work on other systems correctly.

I reinstall the adobe xd many times but it didn't solve the problem.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was the graphic card , i updated the graphic cards and the issue was solved